# Relationship between p-moments and exponential moments of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, improper-integrals

I need your help to solve the following exercise. Let $X$ a random variable on some probability space such that

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(\tfrac{X}{\log(X)})]\leq 2.$$

I would like to show that there exists a constant $C<\infty$ such that

$$\mathbb{E}[X^p]^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq Cp\log(p)\quad\text{for any $p<\infty$}.$$

I tried to proceed as follows. We start by writing

$$\mathbb{E}[X^p]=p\int_0^\infty s^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X>s)\text{d}s.$$

Then, since $s\mapsto \frac{s}{\log(s)}$ is increasing for $s>e$, one can write from Markov's inequality

$$\mathbb{E}[X^p]=p\int_0^e s^{p-1}\text{d} s+p\int_e^\infty s^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X>s)\text{d}s\leq p\int_0^e s^{p-1}\text{d} s+p\int_e^\infty s^{p-1}e^{-\frac{s}{\log(s)}}\text{d}s.$$

I guess that the second integral should gives the leading order contribution $p^p\log^p(p)$ but I am not able to prove it. Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I follow nicely until the last inequality. Where did you get $P(X>s)\leq e^{-s/log(s)}$?

Comment: Using the moment bound on X together with Markov’s inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a rather ugly solution using Jensen inequality. You want this $\mathbb{E}X^p\leq Cp^plog(p)^p$.

Define $f_p(x):=exp(\frac{x^{1/p}}{log(x^{1/p})})$. Then,

$$
2\geq \mathbb{E}f_p(X^p)\geq f_p(\mathbb{E}X^p). 
$$

Computing inverse gives $\mathbb{E}X^p\leq f_p^{-1}(2)$.
This is an ugly part, that I found just using some numerical methods, but it turns out that $f_p^{-1}(2)\leq 1000p^plog(p)^p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! However, I don't think that this is completely correct because $f_p$ is convex only in the regime $x\leq e^p$.